# Vue 3 - Extend a Vue component with additional props with Typescript support

Tags: typescript, vue.js, primevue, vite

I'm trying to extend a 3rd party Vue component (from PrimeVue) and add additional props, but I'd like to keep the typings of the original component and also union them with my additional props.

For example, using the 3rd party Button component below which has typings that enforce "label" must be a string, my IDE (VSCode + Vetur) will mark it as an error if I attempt to pass a numeric.

If I were to extend the Button class into my own component, BaseButton, using the common pattern below, I will be able to pass a numeric or any other type to the label prop without the IDE complaining. Besides maintaining the typings of the original Button component, I want to union it with my additional props, e.g. `myProp: string` below.

```
<template>
  <Button v-bind="$attrs" :label="myComputedLabel">
    <template v-for="(_, slot) of $slots" v-slot:[slot]="scope">
      <slot :name="slot" v-bind="scope"/>
    </template>
  </Button>
</template>

<script>
  export default defineComponent({
  name: 'BaseButton',
  props: {
    myProp: {
      type: String
    }
  },
  setup(props) {
    const myComputedLabel = computed(() => {
      return `Hello ${props.myProp}`;
    });
  }
 })
</script>
```

In my case, the 3rd party component is written in Vue with vanilla JS but has an external Button.d.ts typings file. I'm not sure if that matters.

Comment: Would you mind giving an example? The library does not export the interface: https://github.com/primefaces/primevue/blob/master/src/components/button/Button.d.ts

It exports a class Button, but I'm not sure how to merge the $props field without redeclaring all the props myself.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Vue 3 + `script setup`, you can do it like this

```js
import Button from 'primevue/button';

type ButtonInstance = InstanceType<typeof Button>

defineProps<{
  label: ButtonInstance['$props']['label'] | number
}>()
```

For setup function

```js
import { PropType } from 'vue'

defineComponent({
  props: {
    label: {
      type: [String, Number] as PropType<ButtonInstance['$props']['label'] | number>,
    }
  },
})
```

Another way of extracting types of prop

```
import Button from 'primevue/button'

type ExtractComponentProps<TComponent> =
  TComponent extends new () => {
    $props: infer P;
  }
    ? P
    : never

type ButtonTypes = ExtractComponentProps<typeof Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can read it from the component's `setup` option, the `props` is the first argument of `setup`

```
type MyButtonProp = Parameters<NonNullable<typeof Button.setup>>[0]
```

Simply, here's a Generic Type

```
type ComponentProps<T extends { setup?: any }> = Parameters<NonNullable<T['setup']>>[0]
```

usage

```
type MyButtonProp = ComponentProps<typeof Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Typescript + Setup

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { computed } from "vue"
let props = defineProps<{ myProp: string | number }>()
const myComputedLabel = computed(() => {
   return `Hello ${props.myProp}`;
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience there are multiple ways to achieve this depending on the type complexity and Vue version in use.

### `script setup`

With the introduction of [`defineProps`](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html#using-script-setup) it became less tedious to define prop types (i.e. not relying on casting to `PropType<T>` and less verbose prop definition). Vue 3.3+ [added support](https://blog.vuejs.org/posts/vue-3-3#imported-and-complex-types-support-in-macros) for fairly complex types and `import`ed types also with few limitations.

Here's an example of ComponentB extending ComponentA.

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import ComponentA from 'componentA.vue'

interface AdditionalProps {
  // ... define your props here
}

type Props = AdditionalProps & (typeof ComponentA)['$props']

const props = defineProps<Props>()

//You can also use `withDefaults` to define default values

</script>

<template>
  <ComponentA v-bind="props">
</template>
```

You can even benefit from utility types like `Omit` to remove some Props from the extended component.

Unfortunately, this does not always work because as mentioned `defineProps` cannot handle complex types like "conditional types". I couldn't get it to work with Vuetify.

### `defineComponent`

`defineComponent`'s first generic parameter is `Props` type.

```
<script lang="ts">
import ComponentA from 'componentA.vue'

interface AdditionalProps {
  // ... define your props here
}

type Props = AdditionalProps & (typeof ComponentA)['$props']

const ComponentB = defineComponent<Props>({
  props: {
    ...(ComponentA.props as any) //This line ensures that "additional" props are not handled as "attrs"
  }
})
</script>

<template>
  <ComponentA v-bind="props">
</template>
```

### NOTE ON `SomeComponent[$props`]

While it is not publicly documented editor tools rely on this for auto-complete, as far as I can understand.

You might want to define a util type to extract any component props like this:

```
type ComponentProps<T extends {$props: any}> = Omit<T['$props'], `$${string}` | `v-slot${string}`>
```

The reason why I `Omit` the specified string patterns is that these are internal properties and might cause Typescript to become laggy while editing or reporting errors.

### Extending/Typing slots

Again you could make use of `script setup`'s [`defineSlots`](https://blog.vuejs.org/posts/vue-3-3#typed-slots-with-defineslots) introduced in Vue 3.3. Or rely on a hack that was used in old versions of `vue-router` itself if you want to use `defineComponent`

> Example of using `defineSlots` grabbed from the blog post

```
<script setup lang="ts">
defineSlots<{
  default?: (props: { msg: string }) => any
  item?: (props: { id: number }) => any
}>()
</script>
```

Using `defineComponent` (credit goes to [Abdelrahman Awad's Blog post](https://logaretm.com/blog/generic-type-components-with-composition-api/#generic-slots))

```
<script lang="ts">
import ComponentA from 'componentA.vue'
    
const ComponentB = defineComponent({
  //... component definition
})
    
const AugmentedComponentB = ComponentB as typeof ComponentB & {
  new(): {
     $slots: (typeof ComponentA)['$slots']
   }
}
export default AugmentedComponentB
</script>
```